# select elements that does not exist in database but exists in given postgres array

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want to select elements that are not present in the database, but exist in a postgres array. To visualize:

[image]

Assume that I have this data in my table:

[image]

I have come close after some research, but I do not get exactly what I expected. My current query is:

```
WITH res AS (SELECT entity_number FROM entity_coordinates WHERE entity_number IN (
    'MG1735401016/6',
  'NON-EXIST-1',
  'P171025002876-1',
  'P170321400780-1',
  'NON-EXIST-2'
))

SELECT *
FROM unnest(ARRAY[
    'MG1735401016/6',
  'NON-EXIST-1',
  'P171025002876-1',
  'P170321400780-1',
  'NON-EXIST-2'
]) item_id
FULL OUTER JOIN res ON entity_number=item_id
```

My expected result is:

[image]

I tried different join types but no luck.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you please read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and do what explained there?

Comment: How do you get an array from the table? Is a column an array type and you select one that column for 1 row? Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Bohemian  I added expected result and sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this query should achieve what you're trying to do without any `JOIN`s (`NOT EXISTS` is the most straight forward way to check if any entity_number corrsponds with `str` (element of array)):

```
SELECT str
FROM unnest(ARRAY[
          'MG1735401016/6',
          'NON-EXIST-1',
          'P171025002876-1',
          'P170321400780-1',
          'NON-EXIST-2'
        ]) AS str
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM entity_coordinates
    WHERE entity_number = str
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found another solution that uses `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM unnest(ARRAY[
    'MG1735401016/6',
  'NON-EXIST-1',
  'P171025002876-1',
  'P170321400780-1',
  'NON-EXIST-2'
]) AS t(id)

EXCEPT 

SELECT entity_number FROM entity_coordinates
```

But my benchmarks show that @nafrolov's solution is nearly twice as fast, so I accepted his answer